# Trying to search for descendant using nested functions, running into errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have two classes with objects that contain information about a person and family, respectively. There is a function within the person class that should return true if a given person is a descendant. I can find the answer, but I am at a loss of how to return its value after several nested function calls have been made.

Here are my two functions, in separate classes

Function that is initially called to see if a descendant exists. If one exists i want it to return true.

```
def checkIfDesc(self, person):
    for family in self.marriages:
        return families[family].famDescendant(person)
```

Function from the other class that holds information about families. i.e the children.

```
def famDescendant(self, person):
    for child in self.children:
        if person == child:
           return True
        else:
            return persons[child].checkIfDesc(person)
```

Now, I think my issue lays within the checkIfDesc function and its return statement. If the descendant is not found in the first iteration, it stops searching. If I remove the return statement and basically just iterate through the families I can see from output that I enter the person == child statement.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by implementing these changes:

```
def checkIfDesc(self, person):
return any(families[family].famDescendant(person) for family in self.marriages)

def famDescendant(self, person):
    for child in self.children:
        if person == child:
           return True
        else:
            if (persons[child].checkIfDesc(person))
                return True
            else:
                continue:
```

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
def checkIfDesc(self, person):
    for family in self.marriages:
        return families[family].famDescendant(person)
```

won't do what you want, as you have discovered, because if `self` has several marriages, and `person` is not a descendant of the first marriage, then the function will return `False` without ever checking the other marriages. You could do this:

```
def checkIfDesc(self, person):
    return any(families[family].famDescendant(person) for family in self.marriages)
```

which will stop checking as soon as it finds a descendant.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely covered a scenario I had not thought about! I also realized that it got stuck in the famDescendant function. With your edit and my edit to the function the program works as it should. - Thanks